# R installation for Gurobi 9.1.2 does not work with R 4.0.4

Tags: r, gurobi

As stated in the question: the installation which worked fine in the past seems to be broken. Any ideas how to solve this issue?
There has been a similar issue in the [past](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360069702831-R-4-0-2-and-Gurobi-9-0-2-compatibility-issues), but I am not sure, if it is a similar problem. Although the output only states a warning, the installation does not succeed.

See also [here](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4403376290577-R-installation-for-Gurobi-9-1-2-does-not-work-with-R-4-0-4-install-packages-C-gurobi912-win64-R-gurobi-9-1-2-)

Details

```
 R.version
```

> _ platform x86_64-w64-mingw32 arch x86_64 os mingw32 system x86_64, mingw32 status major 4 minor 0.4 year 2021 month 02 day 15 svn rev
> 80002 language R version.string R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) nickname
> Lost Library Book

```
install.packages("C:/gurobi912/win64/R/gurobi_9.1-2")
```

> Warning in install.packages : package
> ‘C:/gurobi912/win64/R/gurobi_9.1-2’ is not available for this version
> of R
>
> A version of this package for your version of R might be available
> elsewhere, see the ideas at
> https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: Are you following the documentation at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prioritizr/vignettes/gurobi_installation.html? Does the path `C:/gurobi912/win64/R/gurobi_9.1-2` exist? When installing from a local file, you need to set `repos=NULL` as indicated in that installation guide.

Comment: @MrFlick If you like, you can post this as answer. Strange error message for me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing the R package for Gurobi, you need to set `repos=NULL` as @MrFlick already noted in the comments and as is listed in the official Gurobi installation guide for R: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/quickstart_windows/r_ins_the_r_package.html